# "Nicolás Maduro, the president of Venezuela, disproves the modern belief that dictatorship is merely a myth."

Tags: meaning-in-context

Context:

> Venezuela is a country located in South America that has been
> suffering from an ongoing crisis. The crisis started during the reign
> of its president Hugo Chávez, although most of its situation is blamed
> on its current president Nicolás Maduro. **Nicolás Maduro, the president
> of Venezuela, disproves the modern belief that dictatorship is merely
> a myth.** Due to Maduro’s corrupt cabinet, Venezuelans are suffering
> from widespread hunger, electric blackouts, medicine shortages, and
> rampant crime.

What I understood from this paragraph is that the president of Venezuela, Nicolás Maduro, is regarded as a dictator. However, it is said in the passage that he **disproves the modern belief that dictatorship is merely a myth** , which I find confusing because if he disproves this belief, then he thinks dictatorship is not a false idea (**myth**).

Comment: Where did you find the passage?

Comment: In other words, if dictatorship is not merely a myth, it is really a true state of affairs. Careful here with "he disproves"; that means his being the president of Venezuela. Not that he himself disproves something literally. (I assume that the paragraph comes from some blog given the first sentence....)

Comment: to disprove something it to prove that it's not true. So, he proves that it's not true that dictatorship is just a myth.

Comment: @Lambie thank you, it is more clear now, but am I wrong if I say that it is confusing?

Comment: Like I said, dictatorship is a *reality*. Word to the wise: No TOEFL passage would not not criticize Maduro.

Comment: I cannot judge what is confusing to you. We are entitled to find something confusing...

Comment: @winta As comprehension increases so does contextual understanding.  It is a vague statement if taken as a single sentence.  In that case it could be understood to mean that he personally disproves.  Within the context of the paragraph, however, the meaning becomes clear.

Comment: @EddieKal a TOEFL passage (unofficial)

Comment: @Lambie: I think your comment is the answer.